# How wide is the walk?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man built a walk of uniform width around a rectangular garden. If the area of the walk is $207$ square feet and the dimensions of the garden are $10$ feet by $4$ feet, how wide is the walk?

Comment: What  have  you  tried  $?$

Answer (score 1):

Assume  that  the  width of  the  walk  is  $x$  feet  Then   from  the  following  picture  it  can  be  seen  that  the  area  of  the walk  is  :

$$4(x^2) + 2(10\times x)+ 2(4\times x)=207$$
$$4x^2 + 28x -207=0$$

Solving  this  quadratic  equation  you  will  get  $1$  positive  and  $1$  negative  value  of  $x$ .  The  positive  one  is  the  answer

[image]